# Executing Linux-CentOS Command Line via PHP codings

Tags: php, linux, centos, libreoffice

I am wondering if there is any way for me to execute command lines in Linux/CentOS with via a php page? What it does is the command lines will be on this php page and will be run on CentOS to convert and produce a document.

Below is a portion of the code where i am trying to convert documents from .doc/.docx to PHP through the use of LibreOffice.

```
<?php

    $test = "`libreoffice --headless --nologo --convert-to pdf /var/www/html/TERMS/eroom/temp/1_44.docx --outdir /var/www/html/TERMS/eroom/temp`";   
                    echo exec($test,$array);       
                    print_r($array);
    ?>
```

Remarks:

I have tried and researched on numerous ways on how to do this but to no avail. Tried things from shell exec, exec and so on but it does not work. No errors whatsoever and i cannot figure out what's wrong with it.

However if i copy the command line here and execute it directly from the CLI, it works and the converted file is outputted.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried:
system() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php or 
shell_exec() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: I have attempted to use system("libreoffice --headless --nologo --convert-to pdf /var/www/html/test.doc --outdir /var/www/html",$result); but it didn't work either.

Comment: `$PATH` might not being set. Try to use the whole path `/usr/bin/libreoffice` ..

Comment: are you working on a server or on your laptop? on laptops usually you don't have permission to read write in `var` so you could change the permission of `var` to 777 and try again

Comment: Hey, i am currently doing the codings on a laptop. Permission MAY be an issue but i seriously think the codings on PHP could be one of the culprits too.

Comment: if you want to reply to a comment use the `@` followed by the username, so that the person you are talking gets notified, i didn't know that you replied to me, i had to visit the question to see what happened so please next time use `@Fischer` or anyone else... I really think that the problem with the permissions, i had many issues with that, please do `chmod -R 777 /var/`

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini. The exec command probably is given in the disable_functions string. Remove it from this option.

If it is forbidden by safe_mode you probably can turn it on by:
php_admin_value safe_mode off in your webserverconfig (httpd.conf)

For both methods reload/restart your apache/web-server to load the new configuration.

Comment: Hi, i understand what you are trying to say and nope it was not there.